# Query Data on Microsoft Dynamics using SOAPUI / POSTMAN

Tags: rest, api, soap, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to play around using basic queries but I am unable to retrieve anything from my trial dynamics account
I cannot find any tutorials/ EXAMPLES queries to try out...

I have consulted the MS DYNAMICS Web API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/about?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) but it doesn't give examples on how to use it just lists of the metadata one can use.

[This is the screen I get after I import the WSDL to soapui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdkyz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you are using Dynamics 365 i.e Online version of CRM.
Login with Admin account or account which has System admin roles.

Assuming you are on Model driven app screen (i.e new UI)
Go to Advanced setting.

[image]

Then Setting--> Customizations

[image]

Then Developer Resource

[image]

and there you can find Instance WebAPI, that is your Org (instance) WebAPI URL

[image]

Basically WebAPI url is below, try that in browser

https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/

Once you get the Response

you can play around with it as

```
https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/contacts/
```

and then you can also try as

```
   https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/contacts/?$select=fullname,annualincome,jobtitle,contactid
```

Comment: I get how to do that, I wanted to know the following: 1. how to do it in SOAPUI (if it was possible 2. resources that clearly show what metadata / fields can be queried this way with some examples (for inexperieced admins)

Comment: SOAPUI is depricated for Dynamics. You can only use REST i.e Odata way to query Dynamics. For your help there is a Tool created by one of Developer [CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder)

This is what you are looking for.